# Escaping quotation marks in a variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a *sed* command in my script that prints data between specific parts of the text passed to the command as variables:

```
sed -n "$PART1|,|$PART2|p" file.txt
```

Everything is fine until I try a part of the text containing a double qoute. For instance, `PART1 = of the Rings"` and `PART2 = Sauron`.

I've tried changing the syntax to

```
sed -n '$PART1|,|$PART2|p' file.txt
```

However, it didn't like it at all.

Is there any way to automatically escape double quotes passed to *sed* with variables? Also, it is not possible to change the double quotes in the source file.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Does your sed command ever work with anything? `PART1=foo; PART2=bar; sed -n "$PART1|,|$PART2|p" file.txt` fails for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using sed

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat file
something
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
something else
```

Let's define your variables:

```
$ part1='of the Rings"'
$ part2=Sauron
```

Now, let's run sed:

```
$ sed -n "/$part1/,/$part2/p" file
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
```

If you really prefer the pipe symbols in place of `/`:

```
$ sed -n "\|$part1|,\|$part2|p" file
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
```

A concern when doing this is that `part1` and `part2` become part of the sed command and, if maliciously constructed, could do damage to your files.  For this case, it is safer to use awk.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -v p="$part1" -v q="$part2" '$0~p,$0~q' file
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
```

Comment: Is it still possible (putting the variable in single quotes) when defining it with read like this?:
`read -p "Enter part 1: " part1
read -p "Enter part 2: " part2`

Comment: Yes, you can use `read` to create `part1` and `part2`.  The variables may freely contain single or double quotes.  If you want the shell to expand the variables, though, do not enclose the variables in a command using single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Never enclose scripts in double quotes, always single, to avoid unexpected shell interactions and never use all upper case names for non-exported variables by convention and to avoid clashes with builtin variables. Borrowing @John1024's sample input file:

```
$ cat file
something
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
something else

$ sed -n '/'"$part1"'/,/'"$part2"'/p' file
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
```

but more robustly and extensibly you should use an awk script like this:

```
$ awk -v part1="$part1" -v part2="$part2" '$0~part1{f=1} f; $0~part2{f=0}' file
of the Rings"
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron
```

and do not use range expressions. For example to not print the whole range of lines is a trivial tweak with the flag approach:

```
$ awk -v part1="$part1" -v part2="$part2" 'f; $0~part1{f=1} $0~part2{f=0}' file
keep this text
Dark Lord Sauron

$ awk -v part1="$part1" -v part2="$part2" '$0~part1{f=1} $0~part2{f=0} f' file
of the Rings"
keep this text
```